# How to perform segue from tableview cells to different view controllers

Tags: swift, tableview, segue, didselectrowatindexpath

I want to perform segue from tableview cells to different view controllers, not by using the same controller and changing things in it. I have two section as it is seen in the image.

[image]

I did it like this but it didn't work. When both sections are clicked, the same page is displayed:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "toSettings1", sender: nil)
    } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "toSettings2", sender: nil)
    }
    
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "toSettings1" {
        let vc = segue.destination as? ReferencesViewController
    } else if segue.identifier == "toSettings2" {
        let vc = segue.destination as? LiabilityViewController
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have 2 sections? and for each one a row? if yes. you should check this if condition: if indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.section == 0 {} else if indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.section == 1 {}

Comment: it worked! thank you

Comment: I wrote it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 sections and 1 row for each one you should write it as below:

````
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        if indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.section == 0 {
            
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "toSettings1", sender: nil)
        }else if indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.section == 1 {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "toSettings2", sender: nil)
        }
        
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        
        if segue.identifier == "toSettings1" {
            let vc = segue.destination as? ReferencesViewController
        }else if segue.identifier == "toSettings2"{
            let vc = segue.destination as? LiabilityViewController
        }
    }```
````